# Problema con redirección pagina

Tags: html, html5, web

¡Hola! al entrar en una página de mi web me sale error 404 si no incluyo el html detrás, he visto que en algunas webs no pasa eso,es decir redireccionan a la pagina web con el .html si lo pones sin el,¿alguien podría ayudarme?

(paginadeprueba.com/inicio/index)=error 404
(paginadeprueba.com/inicio/index.html=200 Ok

Busco una redireccion del primer caso al 2º sin que salga el dichoso error 404

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario que tengas tu archivo .htaccess configurado correctamente, para que puedes ocultar las extensiones HTML seria algo como:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: ¿donde va ese (1) RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] he de poner la página que he de ocultar? o queda así?

¿y en RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f he de poner los enlaces(nombres tipo index,videos etc)? perdona mi torpeza pero estoy empezando en esto

Comment: Va dentro del archivo .htaccess que va en la raíz de tu sitio web, con ese código ocultara la extensión HTML de todos tus archivos HTML.

Comment: Mil gracias edu

Comment: Edu tengo un pequeño problema,lo expongo aqui para no abrir otra pregunta, no tengo el archivo .htaccess en mi panel no está en la carpeta que "suele estar" error_docs podrías ayudarme?

Comment: `.htaccess` debe estar en la raíz del proyecto. Si no lo puedes ver: o no lo tienes y lo debes crear, o está oculto y debes configurar tu sistema operativo para que muestre archivos ocultos.